# I receive updates for Ubuntu base after every boot

Tags: 20.04, updates, update-manager

I have been receiving updates to Ubuntu base every time I boot, only since a week. These updates are often very small, ranging anywhere from 200KB to 5MB. Is this normal? or Should I be worried?

I have only been using Ubuntu since a month. I am a beginner. So, please don't downvote this question.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on Intel laptop.

Comment: yes this is normal as bugs get fixed in 20.04.

Comment: You didn't tell us anything at all to identify these updates so we can't say for certain, but I'd consider the possibility that you are getting malicious or improper updates to be close to 0%

Answer (score 0):

This is OK. Ubuntu is a very good OS, and developers create some small patches fixing minor bugs very often. This is good, you have nothing to worry about. Just download it.